# Customize frontend and backend yii2.0

Tags: yii2

I have created a website using yii2.0. To open the website's frontend i have to use **localhost:8080/yii2/frontend/web/index.php** and to open backend i am using **localhost:8080/yii2/backend/web/index.php**.

My question is how can i open the website for frontend like http://localhost:8080/yii2/
for **localhost:8080/yii2/frontend/web/index.php**.

and for backend how can i open the website like http://localhost:8080/yii2/backend/ for
**localhost:8080/yii2/backend/web/index.php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md

In short you have to move your /web folders in another place and change the paths in index.php and index-test.php.

Comment: Hello Mihani i am using 
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "yii2/frontend/web"

<Directory "yii2/frontend/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>  
But using this  in Apache's httpd.conf  the apache server not opening in xampp. It is giving error 
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: there is no need to use something special for .htaccess. Just the regular yii htaccess is fine, do not try to do it from .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for reply But i have one question . Can you tell me whole path of .htaccess file where i can paste the code for link
 https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md

Comment: 2 of them 1 in the yii2 folder and another in the yii2/backend folder. But if you ask this then you did not understand at all what needed to be done.

Comment: Hello, Mihai how i understood i am explaing here . Plz make me correct if i am wrong.

1) I have to change index.php & index-text.php so my qiestion is how can i move ? can i do this by changing _DIR__  to my path like localhost:8080/yii2/backend/admin in \web\index.php,index-test.php .

2) i created a .htaccess file in backend\web\.htaccess and pasted the code how given in link provided by you.

3) I modified backend\config\main.php to last paragraph as given in link Separate sessions and cookies

i don't know what to do . please helpe me.
Thanks.

Comment: "i created a .htaccess file in backend\web\.htaccess" - you should not have a backend\web read the link again

Comment: "can i do this by changing DIR_ to my path like localhost:8080/yii2/backend/admin" from your own question such folder should not exist

Comment: Again, you need to take the contents of the web folders and move them in different locations

Comment: Or better yet, why do you even need such a setup? can you explain that part? even on a shared hosting you should still not need such a setup. What is the point of all this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just want to open frontend by http://localhost:8080/yii2/  and backend by http://localhost:8080/yii2/backend. just i want to make url simple.

Comment: Done, just i needed this one
www will be our frontend directory so move contents of frontend/web into it. Do the same with backend/web moving its contents into www/admin. In each case you need to adjust paths in index.php and index-test.php .

This link helped me .
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md

Comment: while i am changeing Separate sessions and cookies section. I am getting login page but while i am inserting username and password i am getting error like Unable to verify your data submission.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use apache or nginx "use test.com" for   localhost:8080/yii2/web/index.php
  and use "backend.test.com" for localhost:8080/yii2/backend/web/index.php

this is vhost.conf in the apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\phpstudy\www\yii_2\frontend\web"
    ServerName dev.com
    ServerAlias 
  <Directory "C:\phpstudy\www\yii_2\frontend\web">
      Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\phpstudy\www\yii_2\backend\web"
    ServerName api.dev.com
    ServerAlias 
  <Directory "C:\phpstudy\www\yii_2\backend\web">
      Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```